# How to design Redis search/scan algorithm using similar subtract in between two dataset options like DB

Tags: java, caching, redis, spring-data-redis

How to design Redis search/scan algorithm within only remaining keys?

```
remaining keys = <All Keys> - <Set of Keys>
```

Background of design:
Our IOT JAVA Consumer applications are running in kubernetes pods with multiple replica.
Number of applications are huge(More than millions) so we use Redis hash to store Appliance's metadata.
e.g. Data sructure in redis is

```
sample Hash - DEVICE|APC2(i.e. for 2nd series appliance)
sample Key -  APC278ER89A1(i.e. Device_ID)
sample Value - Cooking|Claimed|Online(i.e. Device's metadata)
```

For performance improvement we have In Memory JVM cache(i.e. HashMap) also to reduce lookup time in redis

Whenever we receive any message from any appliance we check with device ID, if  in-memory jvm cache contains Appiance meta data if it is not then we fetch it from redis and put it in memory cache, referring it for next time.

There is confiugurable value for maximum data holding in memory cache (e.g. 2000).
if maximum data reached eviction thread will remove it from inMemory JVM cache.

Problem:
Now the problem is whenever we need to lookup in data set present inMemoryJVM cache with that specific appliance id and isnot found then we need to scan in redis for all data again  (including those already scanned in Memory JVM cache) for that hash.

What could be the options to scan in redis within only those dataset which are not scanned/present in memory JVM cache for that pod?

Comment: why do you need to scan? can't you just do `HGETALL`?

Answer (score 1):

> Problem: Now the problem is whenever we need to lookup in data set
>   present inMemoryJVM cache with that specific appliance id and isnot
>   found then we need to scan in redis for all data again (including
>   those already scanned in Memory JVM cache) for that hash.

You're not utilizing Redis Hash correctly, you need not have to scan all the keys of Redis using `HGETALL` or similar operations. You can do `HGET` of the device ID to find the metadata attached to that device ID.

If you want to introspect more than one device ids at the same time, then you should use the `HMGET` command.

All well-known java drivers support these commands.

EDIT:

```
HashMap: id1, id2, id3
Redis Map: id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6 , id7
```

Search `id1` => Already in the hash map do not search in Redis

Search `id6` => Not in hash map search in Redis using `HGET` and update HashMap

Updated Map:
`HashMap: id1,id3,id3,id6`

Search `id1,id2,id3` => All are in HashMap so do not search Redis

Search `id1,id2,id6,id7, id8` =>  `id7, id8` not in HashMap so search these using `HMGET`

Updated Map:

```
 HashMap: id1,id3,id3,id6, id7
```

In this example, I have updated only fetched required keys, but using `HGETALL` I can pull keys.

Comment: We are using HGET only to fetch the device id (if it is not present in HashMap) from Redis using Jedis client. If in same hash suppose many devices are present as keys which are already present in my HashMap and already searched. Here my intention is to skip those keys from that hash whenever next time Jedis client search new deviceId using HGET call so that it will not impact performance. From your comment this seems to me that you are saying when we are using HGET with specific key then this will skip the other keys in Hash that means complexity would be O(1). Is my understanding is correct?

Comment: @DebajitRaha Did not understand correctly, I have updated answer see if that makes sense.

Comment: Yes exactly same I want. what is the time complexity of that  HGET is it O(1)?

Comment: Yes, HGET is O(1)